# Subset of Columns based on the same column names

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I have 2 data frames. In my dataset, a part of column name with leading zeros or trailing zeros should be ignored when matching columns, such as `009 = 9` or `22.0 == 22.` And I want to subset the intersection of column names of two data frames.

As an example:

df1

```
No  009  237 038.1  22.0  010 
1     2    3     6     3    3
3     1    7     6     5    5
7     5   NA     9     0    6
```

df2

```
No    9  237  38.1   010  070  33.5
1     2    3     6     3    2     1
3     1    7     6     5    1     2
7     5   NA     9     0    9     6
```

The result should be like this:

result.df1

```
No  009  237 038.1  010
1     2    3     6    3
3     1    7     6    5
7     5   NA     9    6
```

result.df2

```
No    9  237  38.1   010
1     2    3     6     3
3     1    7     6     5
7     5   NA     9     0
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `trimws()` to remove leading/trailing zero and dot (with the argument `whitespace = "[\\.0]"`), then use `%in%` to compare the two `colnames` and use that to index (`[]`) the original dataframe.

Save the `trimws()` results to new variables (`clean_col_df1` and `clean_col_df2`) to improve readability of codes.

```r
clean_col_df1 <- trimws(colnames(df1), whitespace = "[\\.0]")
clean_col_df2 <- trimws(colnames(df2), whitespace = "[\\.0]")

df1[, clean_col_df1 %in% clean_col_df2]
  No 009 237 038.1 010
1  1   2   3     6   3
2  3   1   7     6   5
3  7   5  NA     9   6

df2[, clean_col_df2 %in% clean_col_df1]
  No 9 237 38.1 010
1  1 2   3    6   3
2  3 1   7    6   5
3  7 5  NA    9   0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. I follow the code but get logi in vector,is any step I missing?

Comment: @mashimena Make sure you copy-pasted everything from my codes. If you have unexpected result, you can edit your question to provide that information (e.g. what is the error, what is your output etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This approach works, although it does produce a warning message due to the "No" column not being able to be coerced to a numeric value:

```
result.df1 <- df1[,which(as.numeric(colnames(df1)) %in% 
                           as.numeric(colnames(df2)))]
result.df1
#   No 009 237 038.1 010
# 1  1   2   3     6   3
# 2  3   1   7     6   5
# 3  7   5  NA     9   6

result.df2 <- df2[,which(as.numeric(colnames(df2)) %in% 
                           as.numeric(colnames(df1)))]
result.df2
#   No 9 237 38.1 010
# 1  1 2   3    6   3
# 2  3 1   7    6   5
# 3  7 5  NA    9   0
```

This is the warning message that will pop up:

```
# Warning messages:
# 1: In as.numeric(colnames(df2)) %in% as.numeric(colnames(df1)) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
# 2: In as.numeric(colnames(df2)) %in% as.numeric(colnames(df1)) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
```